# Node security group rules in aws eks - Startup probe failed: dial tcp 10.0.3.237:8081: connect: connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-security-group

I'm trying to deploy an app in EKS cluster, but cannot get the pod to start - Startup probe failed: dial tcp 10.0.3.237:8081: connect: connection refused.
It may seem it's connected to liveness and readiness probes, but already tried with implementing initialDelaySeconds values, same results.

The thing is, the app will need to use port 8081 and I'm thinking it has to do something with my security groups.
I'm using NAT instance where I did try adding ingress/egress for 8081, no success.
The app also creates an LB which has it's own security group by default and inbound rule for 8081 is allowed from 0.0.0.0/0 as source.

A snip from the deployment.yaml file:

```
spec:
      enableServiceLinks: false
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          {{- if .Values.probes.enabled }}
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTPS
              path: /healthz
              port: 8081
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8081
            failureThreshold: 6
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
          startupProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 8081
            failureThreshold: 3
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 10
          {{- end }}
```

Default EKS security group added for managed workloads has these inbound rules and outbound to 0.0.0.0/0.

[image]

I've been testing with this config as well.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: goproxy
  labels:
    app: goproxy
spec:
  containers:
  - name: goproxy
    image: registry.k8s.io/goproxy:0.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8081
    readinessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 8081
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
    livenessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 8081
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      periodSeconds: 20
```

I'm not an expert in this, and security groups are a bit daunting.
The terraform code in here if anyone wants to try it out (ignore the issue with Prometheus adapter) https://github.com/sweetdandelions/kube-app-slp

Any suggestions/advices are much appreciated.

Comment: On EKS the security groups are generally managed by the cluster itself and should not be manually modified in most cases. Health checks are local on the host and do not leave the network, so security groups don't apply. Where are you configuring goproxy to listen on 8081? Is that its default port?

Comment: The app uses 8081 as default port (snaplogic), I'm deploying in a private subnet if that's what you meant by where?

Comment: The subnet doesn't matter. Your issue is isolated to the host that the pod is deploying to. The host itself can't access port 8081 of the running container.

Comment: The issue was resolved by adding 5 minutes for the probes initialDelaySeconds: 300, but your answer was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: For that type of issue you might want to use the newer `startupProbe` instead. With `initialDelaySeconds`, it makes it so that 300 seconds is now the fastest it will become "ready", but if typically you can solve the same kind of problems with `startupProbe` without the downsides of a high `initialDelaySeconds`